# Create an entity with foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently learning Laravel and I would like to create a new `Entity` with a foreign key in it (basically, a `User` who's linked to an `Address`), so far I'm doing this:

```
$newAddress = App\Address::create([]);

return App\User::create([
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'mail' => $data['mail'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'address_id' => $newAddress->getAttributes()['id']
]);
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a better solution, I just can't figure out how. I'm using the default AuthController generated by the Artisan console.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your relations setup, you can use those to associate the address to the user.

```
$address = App\Address::create();
$user = new App\User([
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'mail' => $data['mail'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

$user->address()->associate($address);
$user->save();
```